# J Unit - test not found

Tags: java, junit

Получаю данную ошибку при проверке с помощью *J unit 4*.

Мой *Main* метод.

В классе импортировал `import org.junit.Test;`

```
@Test
public void main(String[] args) {

    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
     Client client = Client.create(config);
     WebResource resource = client.resource(URL);

     WebResource one = resource.path(INT_R + integer);
     WebResource two = resource.path(DOUBLE_R + d);

     new Service().IntegerValueService(one);
}
```

Ошибка:

```
java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching [{ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=main], {ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=main(appl.test.ApplTest)], {LeadingIdentifierMatcher:fClassName=appl.test.ApplTest,fLeadingIdentifier=main]] from org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest@6438a396
at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:40)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createFilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:77)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неправильно делаешь, в методах теста не должно быть входных параметров, можно из теста вызвать методы с параметрами, используй assert'ы из JUnit для проверки ожидаемого и реального значения. Вот тебе статья - http://devcolibri.com/864

Comment: Андрей спосибо. Скажи может есть ссылка с настройками J Unit только для Eclipse ?

Comment: Ты maven используешь ? Если да то та же самая процедура, иначе советую собирать проект maven'ом

Comment: Андрей я не испоьзую Maven и не собираюсь с ним на данный момент возится.. Я уже проверял свой преидуший проект с J Unit и данной проблемы небыло. 
"Неправильно делаешь, в тестах нет входных параметров".. Непонятен твой ответ.. Что значит в тестах нету входных параметров ?

Comment: Запускать тесты из не статического и не получаюшего параметры метода ?

Comment: Тест не должен получать параметры на вход и тем более он не должен быть статическим и если не используешь maven то просто добавь jar-ник JUnit в библиотеки проекта - вот тебе и вся настройка.

Comment: Так у меня есть эта библиотека.. Я поменял метод на 
public void main() .. Получил ошибку: 
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/core/spi/component/ioc/IoCComponentProcessorFactory""

Comment: Попробуй первый ответ из данного вопроса - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228047/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-in-junit